# Defining discriminants in Grothendieck's Galois theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $E/k$ be a separable field extension of degree $n$.
Assume $\text{char}(k)\ne 2$.
Classically, one may define the discriminant of $E/k$ as follows.
Write $E=k(\theta)$ by primitive root theorem and consider a normal closure $N/k$ of $E/k$.
Then $N/k$ is a Galois extension whose Galois group $G$ has an embedding into $S_n$ (via its action on conjugates of $\theta$).
The field corresponding to $G\cap A_n$ is either a quadratic extension $k(\sqrt{d})$,
in which case we define the discriminant to be $d$,
or $k$ itself,
in which case we define the discriminant to be $1$.

Recently, I've learnt that using Grothendieck Galois theory, we can define the discriminant as follows.
Let $E$ be an etale $k$-algebra of degree $n$, split over a Galois extension $N/k$.
Let $G=\text{Gal}(N/k)$.
Then $E$ corresponds to a homomorphism $G\to S_n$.
Composing with the sign map $S_n\to\{\pm1\}\cong S_2$,
we get a homomorphism $G\to S_2$ which amounts to a quadratic etale algebra $Q$.
Every quadratic algebra over a field $k$ of characteristic $\ne 2$ is of the form $k[x]/(x^2-d)$.
We then define this $d$ to be the discriminant.

My questions:

1. How can we verify that these two definitions are the same?
2. As an example, what would $Q$ be when $E=k[x]/(x^3+ax+b)$? Note that this makes sense even if the characteristic is not 2.

Comment: I see the discriminant as something quite other. At least if  the algebra $A$ is a finite free module over the (commutative) ring $R$, then the discriminant is the determinant of the trace pairing on $A$. If $A$ is separable, then the trace is nondegenerate, and the determinant is nonzero.

Comment: Your $d$ is only the discriminant up to a square, no? In any case, your two definitions are not equivalent, the latter subsumes the former. An étale algebra is a product of separable field extensions... if $E$ is just a separable extension then it's clear they're the same.

Comment: @Lubin That is also a definition I'm aware of, and apparently those 3 definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Yes it is defined modulo $(k^\times)^2$. I'm actually quite confused about $E$ corresponds to a homomorphism $G\to S_n$.